# subset all dataframes in a list based on dynamic conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called 'maxDF'

```
factor max_condition
A       7
B       4
C       6
```

I have a list called 'my list' that contains several dataframes sharing the same variables (column names):

```
mylist <- c('A', 'B', 'C', etc)
```

Example of data frame structure

```
mylist$A
factor condition
A            0
A            3
A            6
A            7
A            8
A            9

mylist$B
factor condition
B            0
B            1
B            2
B            3
B            4
B            5
```

I want to subset these dataframes by dynamic conditions based on the condition taken from maxDF

I can make it manually for each dataframe as below

```
conditionA = maxDF$max_condition[maxDF$factor=='A']
filter(mylist$A, condition<=conditionA)

A
factor condition
A            0
A            3
A            6
A            7
```

I'd like to ask if there is any way to automatically subset all dataframes in the list 'mylist' instead of doing it one by one, as I have 99 dataframes in the real list.

I look forward to hearing your insights.

With kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify your code a little bit using `lapply` to make it work:

```
mylist2 = lapply(mylist, function(x) {
m = maxDF[maxDF$factor==unique(x$factor),]$max_condition;
x[x$condition<=m,] })
```

This returns:

```
$A
  factor condition
1      A         0
2      A         3
3      A         6
4      A         7

$B
  factor condition
1      B         0
2      B         1
3      B         2
4      B         3
5      B         4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(1:nrow(maxDF), function(i) filter(mylist[[i]], condition < maxDF[i,2]) )
```

should do the job.