# Subset dataframes in a list based on regex

Tags: r, list, lapply

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536983/subset-all-dataframes-in-a-list-based-on-dynamic-conditions), but the regex seems to necessitate a different approach. Please mark as a duplicate if appropriate.

I've inherited a series of dataframes structured like so:

```
variable_1 <- c(1, 2)
variable_2 <- c("A", "B")
A <- data.frame(variable_1, variable_2)
B <- data.frame(variable_1, variable_2)
```

I need to subset `df A` to comprise only the row where `variable_2` contains "A", `df B` with "B" etc., which is easy through traditional subsetting:

```
> A[A$variable_2 %like% "A", ]

  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A
```

However, my actual data has lots of these dataframes, so I want to put them into a list and batch process them:

```
my_list <- list(A = A, B = B) 

$A
  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A
2          2          B

$B
  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A
2          2          B
```

When I `lapply` using "A" as an example, everything works fine:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {
    x <- x[x$variable_2 %like% "A", ]
})

$A
  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A

$B
  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A
```

But my lack of familiarity with both regex and list structure in R is preventing me from figuring out how to do this for each `df` within `my_list` with the respective `df` name (i.e. letter). Here's the desired output structure, as opposed to what was produced above (with `????` where the problem seems to lie):

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {
    x <- x[x$variable_2 %like% ????, ]
})

$A
  variable_1 variable_2
1          1          A

$B
  variable_1 variable_2
2          2          B
```

Comment: Will you always have two columns even when you have a third data.frame?

Comment: Also, it's a bit unclear your search criteria. Do you want to always search for the values in `variable_2`? That is, `A`, `B`, `C`, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can utilize `Map()` and specify the `names()` of your list as an argument of your function.

**Code**

```
library(data.table)

Map(function(x, y){
  x[x$variable_2 %like% y, ]
  },
  my_list,
  names(my_list))

# $A
#   variable_1 variable_2
# 1          1          A
#
# $B
#   variable_1 variable_2
# 2          2          B
```

**Data**

```
variable_1 <- c(1, 2)
variable_2 <- c("A", "B")
A <- data.frame(variable_1, variable_2)
B <- data.frame(variable_1, variable_2)
my_list <- list("A" = A, "B" = B)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `imap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap(my_list, ~ .x %>% 
          filter(variable_2 == .y))
```

-output

```
#$A
#  variable_1 variable_2
#1          1          A

#$B
#  variable_1 variable_2
#1          2          B
```